# how to return all the columns not just the updated columns when update in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

let's say i have this update statement

```
UPDATE person set age = 20,location = 'us' WHERE id = 1234
```

based from documentation of postgresql on UPDATE , it can only return updated fields.
but I want to get all fields regardless if it's updated or not

```
RETURNING *
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

`returning *` **will** return all columns of the row that was updated.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.7)

> If the UPDATE command contains a RETURNING clause, the result will be similar to that of a SELECT statement containing the columns and values defined in the RETURNING list

So the `returning *` works pretty much like `select *`

```
postgres=# create table foo (id int, c1 int, c2 int, c3 int, c4 int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into foo values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# update foo set c4 = 42 where id = 1 returning *;
 id | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4
----+----+----+----+----
  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 | 42
(1 row)

UPDATE 1
postgres=#
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b573bd78da2239b2c92fefc70e392456)